# Uploading file and posting form data using jquery ajax in mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I have a form which has some input fields and a file upload.

```
<form id="documentUploadForm"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="text" id="name"></input>
   <input type="radio" id="type1"></input>
   <input type="radio" id="type2"></input>
   <input type="date" id="date"></input>
   <input type="file" id="documentToUpload"></input>
   <input type="submit" id="Save" value="Upload"></input>
</form>
```

I need to post the form along with the uploaded file to my controller action. Below is my jquery script to do that.

```
$('#Save').click(function(){   
var formData = new FormData();
var file = $('#documentToUpload').get(0).files[0];
if (file.length > 0) {
    formData.append("File", file, 'document');
}
var data = $('#documentUploadForm').serialize();
formData.append("Form", data);
$.ajax({
    type: 'Post',
    url: url,
    data: formData,
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false, 
    success: function (response) {
        //do something
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Fail!");
    }
});
})
```

But this does not seem to work. The form collection posted to my controller is always null.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Upload(FormCollection form)
{
}
```

How do I post the form and the uploaded file and receive it in my action method?

Comment: And you controls don't even have a name attribute so nothing would post back! Use strongly typed helpers and bind to your model and post back your model.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, thanks that certainly helped.